# web.xml parameters from non-servlet, outside JSF lifecycle

Tags: jsf, web.xml, context-param

How can I get web.xml parameters being outside of JSF life cycle and outside of a Servlet?
All I could find was related to servlets, jsf requests or specific methods for frameworks like Spring or Struts.

Is it that hard in pure Java EE to get a configuration from web.xml?

In practice

```
getServletContext().getInitParameter("ContextParam");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getInitParameterMap();
```

are both not available.

Comment: In what environment are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and a class, for exampel `AppContext` with some staitc fields

```
class AppContext {
   static String param = null;

   public satitc void setParam(String p) {
        param = p;
   }

   public satitc getParam() {
        return param;
   }
}
```

In the method [contextInitialized](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized(javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent)) read the parameters snd set them to your `AppContext`

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
    AppContext.setParam(arg0.getServletConext().getInitParameter("ContextParam"));
}
```

Use the method`AppContext#getParam()` wherever you want.

[Here a small tutorial on this topic](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/).

Answer (score 0):

When your application loads, you can get this information from your init parameter and save to use in other time using ServletContextListener , something like this:

```
public class TestListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        String yourVariable = servletContextEvent.getServletContext().getInitParameter("yourParameter");
        //Some code..
    }
}
```

Define this listener in your web.xml:

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com.fullanem.TestListener 
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Define your parameter in web.xml too:

```
 <context-param>  
    <description>This is a context parameter example</description>  
    <param-name>yourParameter</param-name>  
    <param-value>Your value</param-value>  
  </context-param>
```

So you store it somewhere you want, as Properties, or global variable, or wherever.